# Should I recommend deletion for code-only answers?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, code-only-answers, low-quality-answers

In the Low Quality Answers review queue, there are only three options for dealing with answers: "Looks OK", "Edit", and "Recommend Deletion". Because of the limited options, I am having trouble with how to deal with code-only answers.

Code-only answers are technically correct, so I hesitate on recommending deletion. On the other hand, they lack enough supporting information to be easily understood and are less useful than answers with explanations.

So, should code-only answers be recommended for deletion?

Comment: The answer has been "no you should recommend deletion" fairly consistently over the years _e.g._ [What to do with code-only answers in Low Quality Posts queue?](/q/300694/15497888), [Reviewing Low Quality Posts - Answers without explanation](/q/260411/15497888), and similarly outside of review queues [Flag 'Try This: {code}' Answers as "Very Low Quality"?](/q/256359/15497888)

Comment: @HenryEcker You mean "no you should NOT recommend deletion"?

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant and what is indicated in the linked threads. (Typing is hard.)

Answer (score 4):

No, do not recommend deletion just because they are code only.

While it is preferable for answers to have some explanation, just viewing the code may be enough for many people to understand how to fix the problem.

Thus they shouldn't be deleted.